# Update null table row fields with subquery predicate based on outer query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to update all the rows in a table that have null values to equal the first entry in a select statement whose predicate depends on the fields in that row.

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET table1.t2_id = 
(SELECT t2_id 
FROM table2 
WHERE 
    table2.timestamp > table1.timestamp AND 
    (table2.col2 = table1.a OR table2.col2 = table1.b) 
order by table2.timestamp limit 1) 

WHERE table1.t2_id is null
```

The errors I get seem to indicate that that it doesnt pass the row columns from the outer query in the subquery. What is the correct way to structure this?

Comment: Which error are you getting exactly? Please edit your question to add this important piece of information.

Comment: You may want to fully qualify the `t2_id` in your inner query, so MySQL doesn't get confused. If that turns out to the be the answer, I can turn it into an actual answer.

Comment: that worked. is there a way to extend it now to update two columns with results from that subquery?

Comment: Do some searching and if you don't find an answer to that second question, we're here for you.